# Cannot read states in Redux with React Hooks, Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a MERN Web-app, which I am learning React Hooks.

What I am trying to do : Access the states in my Redux.

*When i refresh the page*, 
The error : `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null`

I am not able to access it when I clearly see the states in my redux developer tools. 
I have tried `console.log(auth.isAuthenicated)`  but it returns `null`. However, when I do `console.log(auth)`, it returns `[object,object]`. Which confuses me because I can't get inside.

Currently, I am researching and will look into react-persist. I was wondering if anyone can help me with my issue without react persist or explain why it might be a good idea to use it.

My redux :

```
token(pin):"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlNDFmYTNhOWIwZjk0NmU5N2Q5MmY4MiIsImlhdCI6MTU4Mzk0NzA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTgzOTUwNjkxfQ.pysX20n4cxKK5NqcXPosIejSvCN3pbcSNpQvEOX9kBE"
isAuthenticated(pin):true
isLoading(pin):false
_id(pin):"5e41fa3a9b0f946e97d92f82"
name(pin):"admin"
email(pin):"admin@gmail.com"
date(pin):"2020-02-11T00:50:02.183Z"
__v(pin):0
```

snippets of my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TiDelete } from "react-icons/ti";
import Restaurants from "../Restaurant/Restaurants";
import NutritionalGraphs from "../D3Graphs/NutritionalGraphs";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { addItem, deleteItem } from "../../../actions/itemActions";
import IngredientsPredictions from "../Predictions/IngredientsPredictions";
import { loadUser } from "../../../actions/authActions";

import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const UserProfile = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [newUserFavorite, setNewUserFavorite] = useState("");
  const [favArray, setFavArray] = useState([]);
  const tokenRecognized = useSelector(state => state.auth.token);

  // const userID = useSelector(state => state.auth.user._id);
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  const userStates = createSelector();
  // name
  // name => props.auth.user.name,
  // userID => props.auth.user._id
  // foodFavoritesArray => foodFavoritesArray.state.item.items

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser(tokenRecognized));
    // console.log(userStates.userID);
    console.log(auth.isAuthenicated);

    axios
      // .get(`/api/items/item/${userStates.userID}`)
      .get(`/api/items/item/${auth.user._id}`)
      .then(res => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(json => {
        setFavArray(json);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, [userStates.userID]);
  console.log(favArray);
```

it is breaking at :   `` .get(`/api/items/item/${auth.user._id}`): ``

Big thank you for the read.

Comment: Try opening your console **first** and then refresh the page and perform the action that triggers your `console.log`. You will then see what's inside. Also after you refreshed the page you can't inspect objects logged before anymore.

Comment: @trixn Sorry, i forgot to mention this only happens when i refresh the page.

Comment: The error indicates that `auth.user` is `null` and not an object with a property `_id`.

Comment: @trixn it is not null in the redux. Could something be off for my redux tool?

Comment: It definitely is `null` the moment you try to access it. Maybe it is populated only after that.

Comment: Does your `loadUser` action fetch the user? What happens inside that action?

Comment: @trixn that's what i thought, it is initially null. in redux tools, it looks like it takes a second to load. so it fetches that particular second. Do you have any suggestion for this ? No ```load user`` is not able to fetch. the whole page crashes.

Comment: What do you mean with *`loadUser` is not able to fetch*? I want to know if this is where you fetch the user? Assuming that it does you can't directly access the user after calling `dispatch(loadUser(tokenRecognized))` because requests are async.

Comment: @trixn there is no auth state in redux when I reload. I need to load auth from local storage to redux state. it looks like i may need to look into react-persist.

Comment: Whatever that logic is (as you did not show it yet), it probably does something that is async. Please show us the code of the `loadUser` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for your `loadUser` action to complete before you can access the data. I assume that it makes an async request. You need to that in two steps:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch user data when component mounts
    dispatch(loadUser(tokenRecognized)); 
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // check if user has been fetched (will not be the case on mount)
    if (auth.user) {
        axios
        .get(`/api/items/item/${auth.user._id}`)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        })
        .then(json => {
            setFavArray(json);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}, [auth.user]); // perform this when `auth.user` changes
```